# webpack-dev-server compiles but does not refresh my web browser

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I am trying to "hot-load" my jsx components by using webpack-dev-server. This is the command I am using:

```
bin/webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0
```

When I save my jsx code, it interestingly compiles, but does not inform my development web server that the update took place. I have to manually refresh the browser for the change to be reflected.

I am using docker, so I suspect that it has something to do with a network issue. I notice that webpack-dev-server uses port 3035 and my web development server uses port 3000.

Question, when webpack-dev-server finishes compiling, does it open a socket connection to the webserver to make it refresh?

Comment: What does your browser console say ? (F12 > console)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Hot module replacement [HMR] is not working in docker is because of the way Webpack looks for file changes in a directory, it uses `fsevent` and `inotify`. These are modules webpack uses to watch the files in a  specified directory. For [using webpack-dev-server in a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445288/enabling-webpack-hot-reload-in-a-docker-application), its best explained by [Mihail Ignatiev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823972/mihail-ignatiev) and [HosseinAgha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2245902/hosseinagha).

Also, you can change the port number the `webpack-dev-server` command uses by specifying it in the webpack.config.js.

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // It can be changed using port key
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  }
};
```

To answer your question, `webpack-dev-server` will include a script in your bundle that *connects to a websocket to reload when a change occurs* in any of your files. The `--public` flag makes sure the script knows where to look for the websocket. The server will use port 8080 by default, so we can also specify a custom port using `--port` cli option.

Also, inline mode is recommended for hot reload as it includes an HMR trigger from the websocket. Polling mode can be used as an alternative, but requires an additional entry point, `webpack/hot/poll?1000`.
You can use it as follows,

```
webpack-dev-server --inline
```

For an in depth insight into how `webpack-dev-server` uses websockets, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverport).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own problem. port 3035 is needed to be open and available to the web browser for hotloading to work, although I don't know the details.

Ok, I figured out that three things were wrong in my particular configuration. First,
"web-dev-server" needs to be loaded for hotloading to work. So my Procfile.dev-hmr looks like the following:

```
web: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000  
webpack-dev-server: bin/webpack-dev-server
```

I load this file like the following:

```
foreman start -f Procfile.dev-hmr
```

Second, webpack-dev-server operates on port 3035, so you have to open up that port on docker. I did this with the "port" command with the following docker-compose file as an example:

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
      image: postgres:9.3
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
        - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    web:
      build: .
      command: foreman start -f Procfile.dev-hmr
      volumes:
        - .:/myapp
      expose:
        - 3000
        - 3035
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        - "3035:3035"
      depends_on:
        - db
      user: "1000:1000"
      environment:
        - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

3. I had to set the server host for webpacker to "0.0.0.0" (I suppose it's because docker uses some weird ip address). I did this by setting the environment variable: WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

I was able to do this in the above docker-compose.yml script.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this with Webpack 5, you need to add this line to your webpack config: `target:web`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68645260/10800162).